# Java class comparable does not work

Tags: java, comparable

I got a class used in an Android app, which is declared like this:

```
public static class MyData implements Comparable<MyData>
{
   public MyEnum myEnum;

   @Override
   public int compareTo(MyData another)
   {
       if(this.myEnum.equals(MyEnum.Value1)) 
        {  
           return 1;
        }
       if(another.myEnum.equals(MyEnum.Value1)) 
        {
            return -1;
        }
       if(this.myEnum.equals(MyEnum.Value2)) 
       { 
            return 1;
       }
       if(another.myEnum.equals(MyEnum.Value2)) 
       {
          return -1;
       }
       return 0;
   }
}
```

I defined a list: `List<MyData> myList = new LinkedList<MyData>();`

After adding items to the list I call: `Collections.sort(myList)`

The problem is that when I debug, I see the compareTo method being called after the sort method is invoked, however it doesn't enter the first if even that it should. I even put the Boolean expression in Eclipse in the "Expressions" view and it returned true, but the code simply jumps to the `return 0;` and the list is not being sorted like I want to.

Why is that?

Comment: why? there is a return statement after each if

Comment: What is `MyEnum` and how is its `equals()` method implemented?

Comment: MyEnum is just a regular enum. The equals method was not overriden

Comment: What twisted sort logic is this? You are not comparing `this` and `another` to *each other*, but checking for equivalence against two values?

Comment: @JordiCastilla so? I put a breakpoint on the return inside and it doesn't get there even though it should

Comment: I can't understand such expression : this.myEnum.equals(MyEnum.Value1)  ,  a compareTo method is supposed to compare Object 1 to Object 2 of the same class, not Object 1 with whatever else.

Comment: @GergelyBacso what do you mean?

Comment: Just tried out your code and it works fine. The error is not in the code you have posted. How are you constructing `MyData` objects ? Are you sure `myEnum` is set ?

Comment: @Berger and that is exactly what it's doing.. the copareTo method gets an object of the same class and compares them by how I want them to be compared which is by that enum value.

Comment: Perhaps `this.myEnum` and `another.myEnum` are `null`

Comment: I mean that you are doing something really-really strange. If you did not do this weird comparison on purpose (looks like not), then you should read a simple tutorial first. This one is pretty simple: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/24-java-lang/1997-how-to-use-comparable-interface.html . Then you can change that function completely and post a new question if you still need help (probably you won't).

Comment: @VictorWong no, they got a value in them.

Comment: @GergelyBacso I don't really see the difference between what I did and the tutorial other than that my compareTo method gets a parameter of the same class instead of Object

Comment: Oh right, should not be `null`, otherwise `NullPointerException` will be thrown first. Anyway, print the values out to investigate if you still have no glue.

Comment: Well I changed the compareTo to work with the ordinal value of the enum instead of the value itself and it's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I changed that enum class member to an int member which was initialized with the ordinal value inside the Enum.

Then the `compareTo` method was changed like this:

```
   @Override
   public int compareTo(MyData another)
   {
      Integer myVal = this.intVal;
      Integer otherVal = another.intVal;
      return myVal.compareTo(otherVal);
   }
```